# Authentication on Tomcat 8.0.26 via LDAP issue using Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, netbeans

I'm trying to setup my Tomcat server with LDAP authentication.
I inserted following snippet in the server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
                  authentication="simple"
                  connectionURL="ldap://intra.domain.com:389"
                  alternateURL="ldap://intra.domain.com:389"
                  userBase="ou=Benutzer,dc=intra,dc=domain,dc=com"
                  userSearch="(emailAddress={0})"
                  userSubtree="true"
                  connectionName="ldap@intra.domain.com"
                  connectionPassword="{password for the user above}"
                  userPattern="uid={0},ou=Benutzer,dc=intra,dc=domain,dc=com"
                  roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
            />
```

The Server starts without any Exceptions or Warnings.
However, when I try to run a web application a Netbeans popup asks for a authentication username and password.
After typing in the correct credentials and click the "ok"-button, the popup shows up again and again. The Tomcat-log shows no errors either.

Did i miss something here?
Can someone explain, what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.